# aws s3 sync by cron doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron, aws-cli

I run command:

*/usr/bin/aws s3 sync --delete /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads s3://yemaoplanet-blog-mediaassets*

and it works. also, I tried to do command with --dryrun flag :

*/usr/bin/aws s3 sync --delete /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads s3://yemaoplanet-blog-mediaassets --dryrun*

and it works.

but, when I put commands in crontab located /etc/crontab

*/2 * * * * root  /usr/bin/aws s3 sync --delete /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads s3://yemaoplanet-blog-mediaassets

*/2 * * * * root env > /tmp/env2.output

*/2 * * * * root /usr/bin/aws --version > /tmp/aws.output

I could get env2.output that I want to. However, I can get empty file with aws.output. and, no sync with 3s bucket.

Is there any idea I can fix this?

PS. I googled for solving this. so I put absolute path and also, someone talked about region. so, I update aws-cli. but still dosen't work. please help me out !

[my crondtab file's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRVZE.png)

Comment: Can you execute the command "/usr/bin/aws s3 sync --delete /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads s3://yemaoplanet-blog-mediaassets" with root user (from console) ?

Comment: Have you specified AWS credentials for the root user?

Comment: yeah ! I thought, there's a problem with AWS credetials too. Do u have any ideas how to update AWS credentails for the root user?

Comment: Is this being run from an EC2 instance?  If so it's better to assign an IAM role to the instance with the appropriate permissions on the S3 bucket(s)

Comment: Thanks all of you guys.. ! it turns out because of IAM role ! I realized how important IAM role is.. :) have a good programming day !!